# Letter game challenge - Visual basics help-

Tags: visual-studio-2017

A word game awards points for the letters used in a word.  The lower the frequency of the letter in the English language, the higher the score for the letter.  Write a program that asks the user to input a word.  The program should then output the score for the word according to the following rule:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhyli.jpg

**and i have done **

```
Sub Main()
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim word As String
    total = 0


    Console.Write("Word:")
    word = Console.ReadLine()
    Select Case word
        Case = "e"
            total = total + 1
        Case = "a"
            total = total + 2
        Case = "r"
            total = total + 3
        Case = "i"
            total = total + 4
        Case = "o"
            total = total + 5
        Case = "t"
            total = total + 6
        Case = "n"
            total = total + 7
        Case = "s"
            total = total + 8
        Case = "l"
            total = total + 9
        Case = "c"
            total = total + 10
        Case = "u"
            total = total + 11
        Case = "d"
            total = total + 12
        Case = "p"
            total = total + 13
        Case = "m"
            total = total + 14
        Case = "h"
            total = total + 15
        Case "g"
            total = total + 16
        Case = "b"
            total = total + 17
        Case = "f"
            total = total + 18
        Case = "y"
            total = total + 19
        Case = "w"
            total = total + 20
        Case = "k"
            total = total + 21
        Case = "v"
            total = total + 22
        Case = "x"
            total = total + 23
        Case = "z"
            total = total + 24
        Case = "j"
            total = total + 25
        Case = "q"
            total = total + 26
    End Select
    Console.WriteLine(total)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

but the output is 0 i was wondering how to take the full word into account and how to consider for multiple letters in 1 word.

Comment: You need a loop, and you need to read each letter of the word individually as you go through that loop. Your current code only looks at the first letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, Create a dictionary that contains letters and points when form is loaded.
Create a function that returns point value of letter, loop over string with for each loop.
You need a textbox, button and a label.

```
Dim WordPoints As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WordPoints.Add("e", 1)
    WordPoints.Add("a", 2)
    WordPoints.Add("r", 3)
    WordPoints.Add("i", 4)
    WordPoints.Add("o", 5)
    WordPoints.Add("t", 6)
    WordPoints.Add("n", 7)
    WordPoints.Add("s", 8)
    WordPoints.Add("l", 9)
    WordPoints.Add("c", 10)
    WordPoints.Add("u", 11)
    WordPoints.Add("d", 12)
    WordPoints.Add("p", 13)
    WordPoints.Add("m", 14)
    WordPoints.Add("h", 15)
    WordPoints.Add("g", 16)
    WordPoints.Add("b", 17)
    WordPoints.Add("f", 18)
    WordPoints.Add("y", 19)
    WordPoints.Add("w", 20)
    WordPoints.Add("k", 21)
    WordPoints.Add("v", 22)
    WordPoints.Add("x", 23)
    WordPoints.Add("z", 24)
    WordPoints.Add("j", 25)
    WordPoints.Add("q", 26)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TotalPoints As Integer
    For Each letter As String In TextBox1.Text.ToLower
        TotalPoints += WordPoints(letter)
    Next
    Label1.Text = TotalPoints.ToString
End Sub
```

What you need to add is some more handling to textbox so it doesn't accept space, numbers and special characters.
And to customize it however you want.